# How can you set a TI SensorTag to collect data for later retrieval?

Tags: android, ios, physics, sensors, texas-instruments

I'm working with a [TI SensorTag](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag/index.shtml?INTC=SensorTag&HQS=sensortag), and I want it to be able to store the data when my phone is not in range to connect via Bluetooth LE. Currently, the sensor only transmits data when the a device is within wireless range.

By accessing the firmware on the SensorTag, it seems like it should be possible to make it store data even when the phone is not in range and then transmit it when a device becomes available. I'm using an iPhone, accessing it using [their example code](http://www.ti.com/tool/sensortag-sw). I can also use Android code, if someone thinks that would work better.

Is it possible to tell the firmware to log this data locally? If so, what commands need to be transmitted over Bluetooth LE? If not, can the firmware be modified to support this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and wanted to log data when the iPhone is not connected. I resolved this by modifying the SensorTag firmware to incorporate data recording. Essentially I implemented a new service for logging with an extra set of characteristics (like start/stop, reset, log interval, read start, read end, data).

However I tell you, there is quite some modifications and testing required for such implementation. You also need the IAR Compiler and SDK from TI to get started. I implemented temperature and humidity logging only. I was not interested in the other sensors data.

Comment: So you modified the TI software, from the iPhone app? How hard of a hack was it? I tried a lot myself; Haven't gotten code to work

Comment: You can't "modify" the binary firmware (there is only an OAD-upload method for an entire new firmware). So you have to go to the C-Code of the CC2541 SDK and modify the firmware sources. Yes, it is a lot of work and you have to know how to develop in C-code a new profile. It took me several weeks to get along with it... Next you need to develop an iOS app which implements all the new features you want... that takes also some time. You can see some screen shots of my app here : http://goo.gl/QLjKbU

Comment: Hey @Kai, any chance you would open source some of the C code? I too am interested in data logging from the sensor tag

Comment: @user379468 sorry, it may only be available for commercial licensing.